# Extract certain string format

Tags: php, string

I am not good in preg thingy but i found out a function called preg_split.

Let's said i have a string :
`"word1<>word2<>word3<>word4"`

I want to split the the string and extract word 1 to word 4 without the `<>`

How do i do that in preg?

my code :

```
$extractedWord = preg_split(<pattern>,"word1<>word2<>word3<>word4");
```

Comment: Why not just use `explode()`?

Comment: http://3v4l.org/lYAtu

Comment: Trying to improve my knowledge on preg thus i will have more choices instead of explode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your trying to use `preg_split()` instead of `explode()` or other php function that has same results function

```
$extractedWord = "word1<>word2<>word3<>word4"; // values to be splitted on "<>"
$result = preg_split("/<>/",$extractedWord); // execute function to split
print_r($result);
```

Generated Output would be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => word1
    [1] => word2
    [2] => word3
    [3] => word4
)
```

Comment: Thanks but i need all the word inside the string. word 1 to word 4

Comment: You didn't actually test this. Actual result is `array("","w","o","r","d","1","<",">".......)`

Comment: @Kolink yes i didnt try im just thinking off. And also been sorry i just forgot to include `//`

Comment: @Genjo im sorry just did try to run thats why i forgot that in first parameter string to be split should be inside `//`

Comment: always google it at PHP.NET.try to be always active to always view PHP.NET site heres the link for `preg_split()` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Answer (score 2):

Regexes are for regular expressions, not static strings:

```
$extractedWords = explode("<>",$inputString);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$mystring="word1<>word2<>word3<>word4";
print_r(explode('<>',$mystring));
```

Comment: come on man, it's not that complex of a sample. what do you want me to explain, the print_r :p ?

Comment: You could explain why you aren't using a regex like they mention in their question.

Comment: actually, you could just as well use a regex, it would work just as well... just performance